# A couple of things I don't understand about system monitor

Tags: networking, ram, swap, memory-usage

Attached is a screenshot of my system monitor. When this was taken I was running 4 CPU intensive java processes and two perl scripts. A couple of questions:

1. As you can see while RAM is underutilized the system is still going
   into swap. Why is that?
2. I wasn't running anything network related
   that I know of yet there is still a small amount of system traffic.
   Is it something to do with Ubuntu?

[image: System monitor screenshot]

Comment: That RAM isn't being utilised now doesn't mean it wasn't in the past. Linux reclaims swapped pages when there's need for it - and it looks like nothing is asking for whatever is in swap now.

Comment: This situation was fairly stable for a few minutes. If there was swap reclamation I would imagine that things wouldn't be so stable.

Comment: A few minutes is nothing. I have seen swap remain used for days because the swapped process wasn't active

Comment: Is there any way I can verify this is the case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30481314/2072269